# Stop Chrome ignoring ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH for downloads?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download, wget

I sometimes find downloads made using Google Chrome get interrupted, causing files to be truncated. Chrome seems to detect this situation as ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH, but then ignores the error and considers the download to be successful. There is thus no notification that the downloaded file is incomplete.

The code in Chromium which causes ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH to be ignored seems to be [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/download/download_request_core.cc?q=err_content_length_mismatch&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=535).

Is it possible to get Chrome to consider these interrupted downloads as corrupt and thus notify the user to retry? If not, is there an alternative download manager for Chrome, even something as simple as command-line `wget`, which considers ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH (or equivalent) to be an error and either fails or automatically retries?

Comment: I have the opposite problem. Chrome started enforcing ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH errors and I wish to ignore them for an old router. Otherwise the page won't even load!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using chrome a free alternative would be the plugin listed below.

[Free Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager-chr/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp?hl=en)

This is a great program which which will show you download progress as well as errors if you run into any.

I prefer this over using chromes built in down-loader. As I have had a similar issue to yours. *Give it a shot with some of the downloads you have had issues with.*

**For Information on what can cause this issue**

1. This issue can Be server related and nothing to do with chrome or what you are doing. Since the Server handles the request if something in the code is broken you could get a **ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**
2. Could be that there is a proxy in-between you and the connection to the server and it miss handles something. Or it could be your proxy "If you use one".

*-Usually getting to a site means you are possibly going through a proxy at some point or another. This is possible with downloads to. The Download link may go through a proxy to the Server to request the download.*

I hope this information helps.